# Modulus of a very large number, How to calculate $11386^{20635} \mod 31351$?

Tags: number-theory

Having issues calculating mod of a very large number.
Tried to check with previous examples but was unable to understand.

Please help on the follow question.
How to calculate $$11386^{20635} \mod 31351\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

Compute $\gcd(11386,31351)=1$ using Euclid's algorithm.

> Then compute $\phi(31351)=30952$.
>
> Compute the remainder of $20635$ by division by $30952$. This part is not important in this particular example because $20635$ is smaller than $30952$, but it might be usefull in some other computation.
>
> This is to use that $a^{\phi(b)}=1$ mod $b$, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$. This means that if you want to compute $a^N$ mod $b$ and $N=\phi(b)\cdot q+r$ then $a^N=a{\phi(b)\cdot q+r}=(a^{\phi(b)})^qa^r=a^r$ mod $b$.

After this we only need to compute $a^r$ mod $b$.

> To finish this you can use Square and Multiply algorithm. Meaning: Compute $a^2$ and compute remainder mod $b$. Square again and compute remainder again, ...
>
> Express the number $r$ in base $2$ and that tells you which powers you should multiply to get $a^r$ mod $b$.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first part of your answer isn't relevant to this question, right?

Comment: @user92774 That's right. Not to these specific numbers, because it doesn't provide any reduction. So, in your case, I guess it only remains the Square and Multiply algorithm.